# This is a message encoded in a rather obscure foreign language. What language is it and what's the riddle's solution?

Tags: riddle, cipher, language

The following message contains a riddle written in an encrypted form of a rather obscure language lacking a literary standard that is rarely spoken today. What does it mean and what is the solution to the riddle?

Мина кона фути нзима кун голид кодwа мина ази дабука фути лула кун алуминама. Мине мина?

Comment: Are there any hidden hints in the puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is:

> beryllium

first convert Cyrilic to Latin:

> Mina kona futi nzima kun golid kodwa mina azi dabuka futi lula kun aluminama. Mine mina?

It is some language originated to south Africa:

> Zulu, Chewa or most probably pidgin language Fanakalo used in mines

which translates to something like:

> I am harder then gold but easier then aluminium. Who am I?

Comment: There's one other word that could also fall under the definition.